# Parsing News Urls with Readability

Tags: javascript, python, google-sheets, zapier, ifttt

I am trying to automate the extraction of data from news urls with something like 
https://zapier.com or https://ifttt.com.

The main goal is to get a pretty version of news urls' text into a google spreadsheet. Trying to use function like "importXML" fail cause I need to analyse urls with different structures.

I was thinking about to use something like readability.js https://code.google.com/archive/p/arc90labs-readability/downloads to get the html into pretty text, since zapier allows code fragments in javascript or python.

The problem is in zapier you cannot use modules that are not standard to these programing languages (like beautifulsoup) to scrape the urls.

Is there any chance I can pass an url to the code of the readability.js 
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/arc90labs-readability/readability.js
or make an api call to https://mercury.postlight.com/web-parser/
that returns a pretty text?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Yeah, this is totally possible!

The easiest thing today is to make a POST request to the Mercury Parser, which will return info about the article. That'll work for a few months (until their API [shuts off](https://postlight.com/trackchanges/mercury-goes-open-source)). They've open sourced their code though, so if you like them (and I do!) you can wrap their library in a one-off [CLI app](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) and Zapier will run their code for you. To be honest, I'll probably do this for my own use soon and you could use that if you'd like! I'll update this answer when that's ready.

Comment: @xavadid, just checking to see if you built your CLI app for the Mercury Parser yet?

Comment: Hey! Great question. I ended up hitting some unexpected snags with it (namely, their code is too big) and wasn't able to ship a CLI app. I would instead look into [runkit](https://runkit.com/home#endpoint), which lets you host and endpoint and use npm modules for free.